# make sure a JSF web page is not cached according to YSlow

Tags: http, jsf, caching, https, http-headers

In my Spring JSF facelets web application in Jboss6 server I need to make sure certain web pages do not get cached by the web browser for security reasons. And it should work as cross browser as well. I found out when I ran the test in YSlow plugin in firefox the below recommendations.

[image]

In my web application I have a Phaselistener set to disable cache as well. But I still couldn't figure why these results are given by YSlow and I want to know how to resolve this issue by setting the far future expiration date to those static components and improve the performance of this page as well.

**cache control phaselistener**

```
public class CacheControlPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    }

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext
                .getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
        response.addHeader("Expires", "Mon, 8 Aug 2006 10:00:00 GMT");
    }
}
```

**In faceconfig**

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener id="nocache">com.company.jsf.listener.CacheControlPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

**the http header**

[image]

After adding future dates YSlow still display the following,

[image]

Comment: use filter instead... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8185628/617373 / http://stackoverflow.com/a/10657913/617373 / http://stackoverflow.com/a/10854623/617373

Comment: i tried the filter, but still the same

Comment: i want to know how to set the far future expiration date to those static components. Im using jboss server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
response.addHeader("Expires", "Mon, 8 Aug 2006 10:00:00 GMT");
```

8 august 2006 is as of today **definitely not** a "far future" expiration date.

You need to set a real far future expiration date, e.g. 30 days after today.

```
response.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L));
```

#### See also:

- [Web application performance tips and tricks](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/09/webapplication-performance-tips-and.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your cache control and pragma header tells that those resources should be not cached at all. This makes no sense. Remove them. Also, using a phase listener approach instead of a filter approach is clumsy.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I modified my phaselistener accordingly but I still get YSlow displaying three urls. Suppose I cant add the image to the comment box I've added it to the question. pls check and give me some advice Thanks @BalusC +1 for your help so far

Comment: Those files are not been served through `FacesServlet`, but through container's default servlet. A `PhaseListener` kicks only in on JSF requests (and that's one of the main reasons why it's clumsy).

Comment: So there's no solution for that then? will a filter be of any help?

Comment: Either change their URLs accordingly so that they go through the `FacesServlet`, so that any `PhaseListener` will run, or change the `PhaseListener` to be a `Filter` so that it runs regardless of if it's a JSF request or not.

Comment: It still gives "(no expires) https://localhost:8443/favicon.ico". But the problem is I actually don't have a "favicon.ico" in my application as well. How does this point to something which is not there. Damn!

Comment: It's browser-specific request (for the icon left from the URL in address bar). It might actually have returned a 404. No panic, just create one yourself if necessary: http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/

Comment: Thanks @BalusC you saved lot of my time.By the way i had to add 1000L to "response.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L));" because the calculation gives 1 month back, it the data type long issue.