# Browser back button navigation

Tags: jsf

Whenever browser back is clicked, it must not navigate to the previous page but to some default page. how is it done using JSF ?

Answer (score 7):

Clicking on browser back button requests the result page from the browser cache.
This is a client side activity. It doesn't send request to your server for fetching some default page(in your case).

Please refer this post for [writing a filter indicating the browser not to cache dynamic JSF pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185245/redirect-side-effects-when-using-browser-back-button).

And also you can [refer this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407) for more details.

You can try to detect if User has clicked on browser back button by writing client side code.

Refer this post for [detecting back button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser).

If you are trying to alter the behaviour of browser back button, it indicates some kind of flaw in your application.