# How to implement back previous jsf page by clicking on back button on browser

Tags: jsf

Now I encounter one issue related with browser's back button. I hope it can forward to previous page with history when user click on browser's back button. But it always forward to index.xhtml from main.xhtml. I have some operation or page embedded in main.xhtml. Does someone have some idea about that? Or you find the issue of that. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser back button navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493276/browser-back-button-navigation)

Comment: So, you're navigating by ajax instead of by get? Here's then some food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o